# How to set Fixed Product Tax in percentage

Tags: php, magento

I want to add fixed tax calculation of 21% on each product price.

Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this, i googled some topics but those show how to add FPT but not showing how in percentage.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: i am not sure about this.try this instruction this link really useful for your needs http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/fixed-product-taxes and http://theblog.enova-tech.net/2011/04/magento-weee-and-fpt-fixed-product-tax-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks VIVEK For reply but the link you provided add $21 in price, i want to add 21% of product price as tax.

Comment: Got The Way but having small issue that instead of 21% on product price, it calculates 21% on product price+ shipping price. How to solve this?

Comment: Solved Changed file app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php as $shipping = 0; instead of $shipping = $address->getShippingTaxable();